# How to estimate ARMA model for linear time trend

Tags: python

I am receiving a valueError for the following code and am looking to reproduce a typical OLS regression output

```
X1 = df[['time']][start:end]
result_arma = ARIMA(Y, order=(3,0), trend='n', exog=X1).fit()
print(result_arma.summary())
```

My quadratic trend ARMA model was successful because there were 2 time variables and 12 dummy variables but I dont know why this code is prodcuing an error.

Comment: Your question is an interesting one, but appears to be better suited to the Data Science (https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) or Cross-Validated (https://stats.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange sister sites.